# Swift CGAffineTransform Change Initial Size of Animated View

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm performing the following animation on a UIButton called "view":

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
})
```

When the animation runs, it immediately doubles the size of the UIButton, then shrinks it back to its original size. So the animation does work.

But what I would like to have happen is for the animation to start with the UIButton at its original size and then shrink it to half of that size.

Basically, I want the original size of the UIButton to appear at the start of the animation, not the end. How can I do this?

(I tried changing the view.frame.size.height and width properties but that didn't seem to change the appearance of the UIButton or the animation on it.)

Comment: Do you have any other `self.view.transform` in your app?

Comment: Yes, but they shouldn't be active at the same time as this one. Why?

Comment: Suggestions: a completion block, and reset the transform in that block. *or* allow animations to start from current state.

Comment: Why would resetting the animation in a completion block fix the problem if the initial animation isn't working in the first place? And what exactly do you mean by allowing animations to start from current state? What state are they starting from now? (Sorry I'm new to swift/animation)

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. `UIView` animations can be counter-intuitive: one animation not being completed may affect the next one. I will post this code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have conflicting animations.

```swift
UIView.animateWithDuration(
    duration,
    delay: 0,
    options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
    animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
    }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
        // or, to reset:
        // self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```

Starting this animation from `.BeginFromCurrentState` may reduce or remove glitches entirely, and taking action upon completion (which logic you can base upon `completed:Bool`) will also tell Core Animation what to do when an animation is interrupted.

Comment: Setting the transform to identity and beginning from current state actually did fix some other unrelated issues I had. However, it still doesn't fix my initial issue; I think that is a problem with the CGAffineTransform itself not behaving the way I want it to. (It uses the actual size of the button as the end size of the animation, not the start size of the animation.) Is there a way to either a) change that setting or b) change the size of the button before the animation starts?